# Streaming Dataset - Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi

I am making use of the Power BI Streaming Dataset. I have no issues of adding data or visualizing the data. But I have a challenge of deleting the data from the dataset. Is there a way to achieve this ?

I understand the streaming dataset is meant for HF inflow of data. However, sometimes there is a requirement of cleaning/deleting the bunch of the data from the data. I am not able to find the option to delete them ?

Currently i m filtering the Unnecessary using filter. But is there any alternative way to delete from Power BI Streaming dataset.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A streaming dataset's storage is just a cache and it is not exposed at all. It is managed by the service and the data will expire in about an hour. See the [explanation in the link from your post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming#streaming-dataset). You must filter out these records before pushing them to the streaming dataset.